# Can't change directory or access my folders on GIT on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, cd

I have a lot of folders on my desktop, but writing `ls` it shows only 3 of them (which are old and already deleted) on `**git**`. I'm trying to learn node JS but cannot learn because I cannot change my directory.

```
Kamado Tanjiro@DESKTOP-KSUU5FP MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Angela-Yu
$ cd

Kamado Tanjiro@DESKTOP-KSUU5FP MINGW64 ~
$ ls
'3D Objects'/         Favorites/         ntuser.dat.LOG2                                                                               'Saved Games'/
 AppData/             Links/             NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf                                        Searches/    
'Application Data'@  'Local Settings'@   NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms   SendTo@      
 Contacts/            Music/             NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms  'Start Menu'@ 
 Cookies@            'My Documents'@     ntuser.ini                                                                                     Templates@   
 Desktop/             NetHood@           OneDrive/                                                                                      Videos/      
 Documents/           NTUSER.DAT         PrintHood@
 Downloads/           ntuser.dat.LOG1    Recent@

Kamado Tanjiro@DESKTOP-KSUU5FP MINGW64 ~
$ cd Desktop/

Kamado Tanjiro@DESKTOP-KSUU5FP MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ ls
 hello/   intro-day/  'nft50 bigs.txt'
```

[image]

Comment: try `ls -A`. also read the output of `ls --help`. your `cd` looks like it's working just fine.